# Blender three.js exporter breaks scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm using Blender 2.7.7 and the exporter from three.js R76 to export a scene and load it with ObjectLoader into three.js. For some reason the objects in the scene have incorrect positions/rotations when viewed in three.js. Like the model has exploded.

[image: Original model in Blender]

[image: Broken model in threeJS editor]

If I join all the meshes the model displays correctly, but of course then I lose a lot of detail.

What could be causing this and how could I fix it?

Comment: What does *"but of course then I lose a lot of detail"* mean? What exactly do you lose and what does the result look like?

Comment: I lose the materials.

Comment: Seems like Collada and the corresponding loader works great in this case.

Comment: Looks like you need to [apply scale and rotation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3000/935) to your objects in blender.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender, Your Meshes are not set on origin or pivot.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object

So, you can change it in Blender, or set 
            `mesh.position.set(0,100,0);` 
in Three.js